# Encountered problem finding ETL testing or data validation software. Please, help, advise, suggest

Tags: tools

I encountered problem finding tool or software for data validation or ETL testing. I found only 2 solutions: QuerySurge and Informatica.

Advise, suggest any other tool or share experience.

Im sure, given post will further contribute to those who will try to establish validation process like me.

Comment: What are you looking for in a tool that isn't met with the two tools you've found already?

Comment: Everything is ok with those two, but I want to choose more than out of two tools. Are those tools are the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Informatica DVO only works if you have PowerCenter as your ETL tool. QuerySurge works with any ETL tool. Try the free download.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about your experience with these tools? It would help the original poster to know more about both.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal includes test data sets you need to vet ETL operations (across DBs and packages), I would be looking at [IRI RowGen](http://www.iri.com/products/rowgen). It uses the CoSort data manipulation language, which also supports data validation and transformation within test data generations. Compare the outputs of those (consolidated) job scripts to verify your mappings produced the same results against that safe, referentially correct data.